# OnMouseDownメソッドの使い方に関して

Tags: c#, unity3d

マウスをドラッグした時に予測線を表示するスクリプトを作成したいのですが、現在、予測線を表示させたいオブジェクトを「Ball」、スクリプトをアタッチしたオブジェクトを「GameObject」としています。

この時、OnMouseDownメソッドで「Ball」を使用する方法はございますでしょうか？

また、他のコードの記述もある為、できればスクリプトをアタッチするオブジェクトは「GameObject」から変えたくはありません。

どなたか分かる方がいましたら、ご教授ください。

Answer (score 0):

オブジェクトを探す命令は以下のようになります。

```
GameObject ball = GameObject.Find("Ball");
```

この処理は重いため、毎フレームでこの関数を使用することは推奨されていないことにご注意ください。

---

他にも取得する方法はいくつかありますが、「unity オブジェクトを見つける」あたりをキーワードにWeb検索すれば情報が得られると思います。